# Cannot install R with cairo

Tags: r

I' am installing R from source:

```
cd R-3.2.2
./configure --prefix=$( pwd ) --with-cairo=yes --with-readline=no --with-libpng=yes --with-x=no
```

I already have cairo (v1.14.8) and pango (v1.40.6) installed from source (neither had any errors while installing). But R does not configure with cairo:

```
R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /athena/elementolab/scratch/chm2059/from_dat02/chm2059/lib/R-3.2.2

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -I/athena/elementolab/scratch/chm2059/from_dat02/chm2059/lib/bzip2-1.0.6/include/packages/include
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++ 11 compiler:           g++  -std=c++11 -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:         

  Interfaces supported:      
  External libraries:        zlib, PCRE, curl
  Additional capabilities:   NLS
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      PNG, JPEG, TIFF, cairo, ICU
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes

configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
```

I see these lines while it configures:

```
checking for X... disabled
using X11 ... no
checking whether pkg-config knows about cairo and pango... yes
checking whether cairo including pango is >= 1.2 and works... no
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42586131/2022326

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in [Why do Greek letters fail to render in R's (v4) PDF output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65150098) - this is how I fixed it for R 4.0.3:

Open the `configure` script, and find this:

```
$as_echo_n "checking whether cairo including pango is >= 1.2 and works... " >&6; }
if ${r_cv_cairo_works+:} false; then :
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  cat confdefs.h - <<_ACEOF >conftest.$ac_ext
/* end confdefs.h.  */

#include <pango/pango.h>
#include <pango/pangocairo.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#if CAIRO_VERSION  < 10200
#error cairo version >= 1.2 required
#endif
int main(void) {
    cairo_t  *CC = NULL; // silence picky compilers
    cairo_arc(CC, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 6.28);
    pango_cairo_create_layout(CC);
    pango_font_description_new();
    return 0;
 }

_ACEOF
```

Copy this core code part into some `test.c` file:

```
#include <pango/pango.h>
#include <pango/pangocairo.h>
#include <cairo-xlib.h>
#if CAIRO_VERSION  < 10200
#error cairo version >= 1.2 required
#endif
int main(void) {
    cairo_t  *CC = NULL; // silence picky compilers
    cairo_arc(CC, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 6.28);
    pango_cairo_create_layout(CC);
    pango_font_description_new();
    return 0;
 }
```

Then run `cc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pangocairo)`. This may give you some more information on why the `configure` test is failing. Also use

```
cc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pangocairo) --verbose
```

and

```
cc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pangocairo) -Wl,--verbose
```

to obtain even more information.

In my case, I finally got this after installing a few missing packages:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The reason was a broken link in `/usr/lib64`:
[image]

Once that was repaired, everything worked: lacking root right, I used

```
mkdir ~/lib
cp /usr/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0 ~/lib/libharfbuzz.so
export LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib
```

Then, `cc test.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pangocairo)` finished, and configuring with pango and cairo worked as well.